# serializing nested model objects in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

say i have some models in one of my apps in the django project as follows:

```
class BaseModel(Model):
    # some fields...

class FirstNestedLevel(Model):
    parent_id = ForeignKey(BaseModel)
    # other fields

class SecondNestedLevel(Model):
    parent_id = ForeignKey(FirstNestedLevel)
    # other fields

class ThirdNestedLevel(Model):
    parent_id = ForeignKey(SecondNestedLevel)
    # other fields
```

It looks fine when there is only 2 level of nested objects to override the create and update methods on each serializer to make them work, but what if we have more levels of nested objects?

I usually do this by implementing create and update methods to handle one level down and pass downer objects to their own serializer to do the rest.

Is there a better way to implement serializer classes?